# Create a folder on local computer in PHP

Tags: php, directory, mkdir

How can I create a folder not on the server, but in my computer (Profile/AppData/Local/Fyooz/).

my sample code:

```
    $file = "Profile/AppData/Local/Fyooz/";

    if(file_exists($file)) {
        echo "file exist";
        echo $file;
    } else {
        mkdir($file, 0777);
    }
```

but it returns an error, because it will open the domain folder not my local computer.

Comment: You can't, PHP runs on the server

Comment: Phil, you can run PHP locally like any other scripting language

Comment: @macek then that local computer running PHP is the "server", but I think the question implies that the server is *not* the local computer.

Comment: Yeah thanks, but i don't want to run php locally.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan what is your end goal? Why are you trying to modify the user's file system?

Comment: @macek I just want to create folder and save a text file on that directory. I am currently creating a widget for now, it is for notification purposes. I am using api, one way I think to get my access token is to save this token to that text file and retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only create a folder on your local computer if you're running your PHP script locally.

If you're trying to run a PHP script on a webserver and create a folder on the client's computer, this is not possible (as you already see a lot of other people saying).

---

Here's a sample script to try. Save it to `~/myscript.php`

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

chdir('~');
if(mkdir('helloworld')){
  echo "yay!";
}
else {
  echo "fail :(";
}
```

Open a terminal and run your script

```
$ php ~/my_script.php
```

You should see output like this

```
yay!
```

Navigate to `~` and you should see your new `helloworld` folder

---

Answer (score 2):

you can't do this.  php is a server side language, so all code is executed on the server, not the client machine.

Comment: You can run PHP locally, too.

Comment: Ah yeah, I was thinking about that. I just need someone will confirm it to me. Thanks, but is there other way can I do that? If not on PHP, well I think I can do that in javascript.

Comment: @macek, and then your local machine is the server.  i don't understand the downvote, as the accuracy of the information is there, and it clearly answers the question.  whatever though.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan For security reasons no browser gives any website access to the file system to create a file.

Comment: @nathangonzalez People just like to down vote here.  I dont get it.  Let it roll like water off a ducks back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create the folder using php. Just create a java applet and refer that applet in your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create directory in you local machine if php script has been on the server. But if you have php script in your local machine then you can create the folder directory in your local machine but before that  you have to use logic and php functionality to be created the folder directory. Then assume that you have applyed logic to cretate folder directory then you have also hosted created website then it will create folder directory on the server or it may be genrated error.